# Matrix-Norm inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, matrix-norms

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times  n}$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert a_{ij} \rvert \le C $$ $$j=1,2,\dots,n$$
Show that , for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times  n}$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert (Ax)_i \rvert \le C\lVert x\rVert_1$$
Also find a non-zero vector $x$ for which the equality holds
I tried to take the given inequality and multiply with the norm-1 of the vector $x$ but cannot go on since the multiplication of the summads cannot be fused into one.Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching the order of summations for the 3rd equality below, we have:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert (Ax)_i \rvert=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j}|a_{ij}x_j|=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_j|a_{ij}||x_j|=\sum_j|x_j|\left(\sum_i|a_{ij}|\right)\leq C\sum_j|x_j|
$$
which gives you the desired inequality.

A non-zero $x$ to make the inequality an equality does not generally exist. For example, take $n=1$, $A=(1)$, and $C=2$.

Comment: In general we cannot find a non-zero $x$ for which the inequality becomes an equality is because we have an unknown constant C?

Comment: @Manyquestions To achieve equality, $x_j$ can be nonzero whenever $C$ is equal to $\sum_i|a_{ij}|$. If $C$ is strictly bigger than $\sum_i|a_{ij}|$ for all $j$, then no non-zero $x$ exists that will make equality.